# Why does Excel 2010 VBA hide rows when applying AutoFilter?

Tags: excel, vba

[image: New Image][image: IMAGE file]

Hello,

For some reason in Excel 2010 and 2016 when I apply a filter it collapses the rows. This means when I try and copy and paste to another worksheet only the column headers are copied. (image attached)

I have tried to unhide the rows and change the row height etc. (both manually and with VBA) but unless I do all 200+ rows manually the macro fails. On excel 2007 it works fine because it doesn’t collapse the rows.

The line of code is this:

Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria:=Range("A1").Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

**** I have added a new image, unless I manually drag out the rows, they remain hidden even though there is data there***

I just don't understand why all the rows are hidden??

Comment: I guess none of the rows matched your filter.

Comment: You know you are filtering by the value of Range("A1"), which by your example seems to be the header, so unless you have data in that column that is the same as the header it doesn't look like it would work... Regarding the fact that it works in 2007, do you have the same data on Column A? If you were to share with us some dummy data, then at least we could test the outcomes?

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the issue, its just that excel 2010 and 2016 seems to hide the rows after applying the filter. In Excel 2007 the filtered rows are visible